# SSRS show list of weeks

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

Is there a way I can create a list of weeks `(param):w1,W2,...` based on another param list (years), so the first list is for the years and the second is for the weeks corresponding to the chosen year.

For example if I choose 2017 from my first list my second list (weeks) should be updated with labels W1,W2,... & the values are the corresponding dates in the given year.

Comment: What have you done so far? What is the start day of your week? Monday?

Comment: can you post a sample of your data that contains your years and weeks.#

Comment: MiguelH , I need to take the iso week & the start of the week is Monday

Comment: Hi Alan ,my data does not contain weeks only a column with date .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ...

```
declare @year as int    
declare @startdate as datetime
declare @wk as int
declare @endwk as datetime
declare @tbl as table (
  tbl_wk int, 
  tbl_Monday datetime
)
set @endwk= (SELECT DATEPART(wk, GETDATE())+1)
set @wk = 1
set @year = '2017'
set @startdate = CAST (cast(@year as varchar(4))+ '/01/01 00:00:00' as datetime)
while (@wk < @endwk)
  begin
   insert into @tbl (tbl_wk,tbl_Monday)
   select @wk,DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,@startdate), 0) as monday--MondayOfCurrentWeek,
   set @wk = @wk+1
   set @startdate = @startdate+7
end

select * from @tbl
```

Answer (score 0):

You could adapt this to create a table in SQL and then reference this in your report.
Note: You could include Year in an outer loop if you need dates from more than one year

```
declare @year as int    
declare @startdate as datetime
declare @wk as int
declare @tbl as table (
  tbl_wk int, 
  tbl_Monday datetime
)

set @wk = 1
set @year = '2017'
set @startdate = CAST (cast(@year as varchar(4))+ '/01/01 00:00:00' as datetime)
while (@wk < 53)
  begin
   insert into @tbl (tbl_wk,tbl_Monday)
   select @wk,DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,@startdate), 0) as monday--MondayOfCurrentWeek,
   set @wk = @wk+1
   set @startdate = @startdate+7
end

select * from @tbl
```

Comment: Miguel , I think it will work fine for me .if I want to show only the weeks from the start of the year to the current week ,it's possible to add a condition in sql or i can play with Hide/display in ssrs?  Thank you